# Why is .addClass() and .removeClass() not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've googled and googled as well as search Stackoverflow. After looking though about 2 dozen other questions and not seeing the same situation, I decided to post a new question.

I don't need help getting this working. I just want to understand **why** it's not working. It just doesn't make any sense to me. So, my question is this:

**Why would saving the jQuery object to a variable cause `.addClass()`/`.removeClass()` to not work?**

---

### **What I'm trying to do**

I have a `span`  with class `fa fa-eye` and I want to change the `fa-eye` class to `fa-eye-slash` and back again with a button click.

---

### **What's not working**

Here's my HTML:

```
<button id='visibility-toggle' data-status='hidden'>
  <span class='fa fa-eye'></span>
  Show
</button>
```

Here's my *not working* JavaScript:

```
jQuery('#visibility-toggle').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var button = jQuery(this);
  var icon = button.find('.fa');
  if(button.data('status') === 'hidden') {
    show_stuff();
    button.html(button.html().replace('Show', 'Hide'));
    icon.addClass('fa-eye-slash');
    icon.removeClass('fa-eye');
    button.data('status', 'visible');
  } else {
    hide_stuff();
    button.html(button.html().replace('Hide', 'Show'));
    icon.addClass('fa-eye');
    icon.removeClass('fa-eye-slash');
    button.data('status', 'hidden');
  }
});
```

The string replacement is working and the show/hide functionality is working. The add/remove class functionality is not working.

I also tried making these changes.

HTML:

```
  <span class='show-icon fa fa-eye'></span>
```

JS:

```
  var icon = jQuery('.show-icon');
```

...still not working.

---

### **What is working**

**BUT** here's the kicker. This *works* (not saving the jQuery object to a `icon` variable, but just looking it up each time):

```
jQuery('#visibility-toggle').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var button = jQuery(this);
  if(button.data('status') === 'hidden') {
    show_stuff();
    button.html(button.html().replace('Show', 'Hide'));
    jQuery('.show-icon').addClass('fa-eye-slash');
    jQuery('.show-icon').removeClass('fa-eye');
    button.data('status', 'visible');
  } else {
    hide_stuff();
    button.html(button.html().replace('Hide', 'Show'));
    jQuery('.show-icon').addClass('fa-eye');
    jQuery('.show-icon').removeClass('fa-eye-slash');
    button.data('status', 'hidden');
  }
});
```

So, again, my question is:
**Why would saving the jQuery object to a variable cause `.addClass()`/`.removeClass()` to not work?**

I have been working with jQuery for years and have never noticed this behavior before. It seems very strange. Am I just missing something super simple? Am I just too tired?

---

### Additional info

I am seeing this behavior in `Google Chome Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit)` on `Ubuntu 14.04.3`. I have not tried other browsers or other systems.

I'm using `jQuery 2.1.3` from: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js

If I run this code in the console, it works as expected.

```
var icon = jQuery('.show-icon');
icon.addClass('fa-eye-slash');
icon.removeClass('fa-eye');
icon.addClass('fa-eye');
icon.removeClass('fa-eye-slash');
```

When I `console.log(icon)` and `console.log(jQuery('.show-icon'))` in the console, they look exactly the same.

```
[span.show-icon.fa.fa-eye, prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: ".show-icon"]
```

I am able to consistently toggle the code back and forth and one way it works, the other way it doesn't.

---

### EDIT: This is what is now working as expected

HTML:

```
<button id='visibility-toggle' data-status='hidden'>
  <span class='fa fa-eye'></span>
  <span class='text'>Show</span>
</button>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('#visibility-toggle').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var button = jQuery(this);
  var icon = button.find('.fa');
  var text = button.find('.text');
  if(button.data('status') === 'hidden') {
    show_stuff();
    text.text(text.text().replace('Show', 'Hide'));
    icon.addClass('fa-eye-slash');
    icon.removeClass('fa-eye');
    button.data('status', 'visible');
  } else {
    hide_stuff();
    text.text(text.text().replace('Hide', 'Show'));
    icon.addClass('fa-eye');
    icon.removeClass('fa-eye-slash');
    button.data('status', 'hidden');
  }
});
```

I know it's ugly. I'll refactor it in the morning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you replace a chunk of the document with `.html()` you are throwing away all of the DOM objects that represent those elements and a bunch of new ones get created. Your saved copy of icon refers to the thrown-away object that got replaced by `.html`. Avoid `.html` like the plague - modify the object properly with `.attr`, `.text`, `.empty` `.append`, etc. `.html` is a security hole waiting to happen.

Comment: Yeah, that's *exactly* it. I should have seen that. Thanks! It's been a long day.

Comment: If you find that `.text()` is blowing away something else in there, like an icon, then you may want to put the text in a span, so the icon and text (span) are siblings under the parent. Then you can securely use `.text` to change the span text, without disturbing the icon.

Comment: Yeah, that exactly what I did. Thanks. It's working fine now.